# Delete Rows with duplicate fields in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a database (table name is campaigns_eventfire) with duplicate events for contacts and I'd like to delete all duplicates so each contact id has just one event.

Here's what my table looks like:

| ID | CONTACT_ID | EVENT_ID | SCHEDULED |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 8,854 | 1,187 | 02/08/2 06:00 |
| 2 | 8,854 | 1,187 | 02/08/2 06:00 |
| 3 | 8,854 | 1,187 | 02/08/2 06:00 |
| 4 | 8,854 | 1,187 | 02/08/2 06:00 |
| 5 | 8,854 | 1,187 | 02/08/2 06:00 |
| 6 | 8,854 | 1,187 | 02/08/2 06:00 |
| 7 | 8,854 | 1,187 | 02/08/2 06:00 |
| 8 | 8,854 | 1,187 | 02/08/2 06:00 |
| 9 | 8,854 | 1,187 | 02/08/2 06:00 |
| 10 | 8,854 | 1,187 | 02/08/2 06:00 |
| 11 | 8,854 | 1,187 | 02/08/2 06:00 |
| 12 | 8,854 | 1,187 | 02/08/2 06:00 |
| 13 | 9,124 | 1,145 | 02/08/2 06:00 |
| 14 | 9,124 | 1,145 | 02/08/2 06:00 |
| 15 | 10,570 | 924 | 02/08/2 06:00 |
| 16 | 10,570 | 924 | 02/08/2 06:00 |

Contact_ID 8854 with event_id 1187 appears twelve times which means that the contact is scheduled for the same event 12 times which is wrong.

Contact_ID 9124 with event_id 1145 appears two times.

Contact_ID 10,570 with event_id 924 appears two times

Here's what I want the table to look like after deletion.

| ID | CONTACT_ID | EVENT_ID | SCHEDULED |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 8,854 | 1,187 | 02/08/2 06:00 |
| 13 | 9,124 | 1,145 | 02/08/2 06:00 |
| 15 | 10,570 | 924 | 02/08/2 06:00 |

It doesn't matter which ID gets deleted, so long as the duplicates are removed.
I have around 600 affected records so deleting one at a time is just not practical.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a job for `DELETE USING`.

```
DELETE FROM t c1 USING t c2
WHERE c1.contract_id = c2.contract_id AND
      c1.id > c2.id;
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=695f51ee61f7973db9d38ba6e5c1270b)

Further reading: [`How To Delete Duplicate Rows in PostgreSQL`](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/how-to-delete-duplicate-rows-in-postgresql/)

Answer (score 2):

Aggregation does what you want as a query:

```
SELECT MIN(ID), CONTACT_ID, EVENT_ID, SCHEDULED
FROM T
GROUP BY CONTACT_ID, EVENT_ID, SCHEDULED;
```

If you want to delete the rows, then you can use a correlated subquery:

```
delete from t
    where t.id > (select min(t2.id)
                  from t t2
                  where t2.contact_id = t.contact_id and
                        t2.event_id = t.event_id and
                        t2.scheduled = t.scheduled
                 );
```